# about the difference between "tbl_df" , "tbl" , and "data.frame" and error message

Tags: r

Hi when I calculate the distance matrix using StatMatch package, I got an error message saying that "Error in FUN(X, Y, ...) : non-numeric argument to binary operator"
At this point, class(df) was [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame".

When I used,

```
   df<-as.data.frame(df)
```

It worked, but I would like to know the reason.

Comment: Can you provide something reproducible here? Perhaps `dput(head(df))` (before your conversion above).

Comment: I wonder if this expains: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tibbles.html#interacting-with-older-code

Comment: Please share data and code which generated the error.